# Unable to handle room migration properly

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to handle migration with this code:

```
private val MIGRATION_1_2=object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CalendarModel`(`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,`calendarDate` INTEGER NOT NULL,`isSelected` INTEGER NOT NULL)")
            }
        }
```

My model class is:

```
@Entity
data class CalendarModel(@PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true) val id:Int=0,
                         @ColumnInfo(name="CalendarDate") val calendarDate:Long,
                         @ColumnInfo(name="IsSelected") val isSelected:Int
                         )
```

But what error i'm receiving after migration is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: CalendarModel(com.package_name).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='CalendarModel', columns={CalendarDate=Column{name='CalendarDate', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, IsSelected=Column{name='IsSelected', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='CalendarModel', columns={isSelected=Column{name='isSelected', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, calendarDate=Column{name='calendarDate', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

expected table is the same but in reverse order. and by reversing my order in entity no difference is occuring.
please help if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Yeldar.N for pointing me out, the glitch was in variable it is was such a silly mistake i have made.

```
private val MIGRATION_1_2=object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CalendarModel`(`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,`calendarDate` INTEGER NOT NULL,`isSelected` INTEGER NOT NULL)")
            }
        }
```

it is required CalendarDate instaed of calendarDate and IsSelected instead of isSelected like below.

```
private val MIGRATION_1_2=object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CalendarModel`(`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,`CalendarDate` INTEGER NOT NULL,`IsSelected` INTEGER NOT NULL)")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CalendarModel`(`id` INTEGER NOT NULL,`calendarDate` INTEGER NOT NULL,`isSelected` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))"
```

**Update**

Add this into build.grade(app), inside `defaultConfigs`:

```
javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation":
                                      "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
```

And inside `app/schemas/your_package/` you will find json file.
Copy value from **createSql** into `database.execSQL`

Comment: Well i did but this one too is not working.

Comment: Trust me brother I already have tried these all things but the same error occur again and again

Comment: Is there any other way remaining to try?

Comment: you have different naming `calendarDate` and `CalendarDate`, `isSelected` and `IsSelected` in column name and in execSQL

Comment: I think best way is to store them in the const variables.